# Differential Equation on rate of spread of a rumor.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

So there is this question that I have been trying to solve but am struggling to do so. As far as I can tell, it is a differential equation however, I am unsure how to go about solving it. It would be very much appreciated if any help was given on the question as I am unsure of how to proceed with it. Thank you.

> A rumor is spread at a rate proportional to the number of people who have heard it. If there are $200$ people in a room and the amount of people who have heard the rumor is unknown, then it must be assumed that $200 - x$ have heard the rumor. Therefore the rate is:
>   $$\dfrac{dx}{dt} = ax(200 - x)$$
>   It is assumed that the rumor started with one person and that after $1.5$ hours, $12$ people have heard it. How long will it take for $100$ people to hear the rumor?

Comment: How did you find $dx/dt = ax(200 - x)$?

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{dx}{dt} = ax(200 - x), \frac{dx}{ax(200-x)}=dt$, integrating both parts we get $\frac{1}{200a}ln(\frac{x}{200-x})=t+c$. Using given initial conditions, you can find $a$ and $c$. Finally you set $x=100$ and find $t$